# PHP, how to remove HTML special characters for a string?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to form HTML in my PHP code, something like this:

```
$output .= '<div>'.$text.'</div>;

echo $output;
```

however, I found $text might have some html characters, such as `>`, `<`, `'`, `"`, etc... and this will make the final html corrupted.

I was thinking to remove `> < ' "` from $text, but maybe there are more characters I should remove? And what's the best way to do it?

Comment: I think you need to learn how to learn.

Comment: dont judge before knowing something deep enough

Comment: I'm not judging. I'm telling you how to improve yourself. You could have gotten the answer to your question by simply using `> insert your favorite search engine <` and it's probably way faster than writing the whole question and reading the answer(s) below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHP function [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is your friend.

I've put an example from php.net below to show how it works:

```php
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

**N.B.** When reading php.net pages, take time to scan through the comments of any functions/ classes you might be thinking of using as they often contain real world examples of issues you may encounter.

However, I'm not entirely certain you should have asked this question, because a quick Google would have returned the results you're looking for. If you see StackOverflow or PHP.net results which seem on topic, then they're well worth a browse before posting a question which may have been asked before.

Comment: yes, before I asked I already googled and found htmlspecialchars should be the one I need. I think I didn't specify my question enough. But anyway, thanks for the reply & info.

Comment: The standard set of characters translated by htmlspecialchars should be enough - you are unlikely to need extra ones.